# Imagemosaic with CoverageNameCollector

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, sentinel-2

I'm trying to get an Imagemosaic of Sentinel2 data with one coverage for each band to work.

As described in the [docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html#indexer-properties), I want to make use of the CoverageNameCollector property. But the docs are very vague about it and I cannot get it to work. I always end up with just one Coverage.

Beisdes the official docs, I did not find any other source for documentation or tutorial.

My `indexer.properties` file looks like this:

```
GranuleAcceptors=org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.acceptors.HeterogeneousCRSAcceptorFactory
GranuleHandler=org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulehandler.ReprojectingGranuleHandlerFactory
HeterogeneousCRS=true
MosaicCRS=EPSG\:4326
TimeAttribute=time
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](time),CRSExtractorSPI(crs)
CoverageNameCollector=org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.namecollector.FileNameRegexNameCollectorSPI:regex=(B[0-1][0-9]).jp2$
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,time:java.util.Date,crs:String
CanBeEmpty=true
```

Example Filename: `T60VXJ_20170421T232711_B03.jp2`

I use current development snapshot of GeoServer (2.12).

Comment: please edit your question to give us examples of the file names used, and what is in the log file (on Developer-DEBUG) when you try to create the mosaic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working, there were two issues with my *indexer.properties*:

1. The name of the Property is **CoverageNameCollectorSPI** instead of **CoverageNameCollector**. It was a typo in the docs, but got updated (thanks @Daniele Romagnoli)
2. FileNameRegexCollector uses the **BaseName** of the file so the extension is not part of the parsing.

---

Working solution:

```
CoverageNameCollectorSPI=org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.namecollector.FileNameRegexNameCollectorSPI:regex=_(B[018][0-9A])
```